# Why is my Unity 2D character not flipping?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

My character is moving just fine. But it is not flipping. Is there anything wrong in my script?
It's my first time developing a demo game for practice, so I would be glad if someone helps me.

```cs
public class movement2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 100;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(inputX, 0, 0)*speed;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(movement);

        Vector2 CharacterScale = transform.localScale;

        if (inputX < 0) 
        { 
            CharacterScale.x = -1;
        }

        if (inputX > 0)
        {
            CharacterScale.x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't assign the value of transform.localscale you just change the local variable.

```cs
    if (inputX < 0) 
    { 
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }

    if (inputX > 0)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
```